# How to Show logical Ids on table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table of employees and their floor as shown:

```
ID        EmployeeId   EmpName  FloorId       

1           abc123       abc       1      
2           xyz123       xyz       1
3           def123       def       2
4           pqr123       pqr       2
```

I have shown result from table on floor wise basis,but when I shows 2nd floor employees I want result to be shown like this:

> `select * from tblname where FloorId=2`

```
ID        EmployeeId   EmpName  FloorId 

1           def123       def       2
2           pqr123       pqr       2
```

Comment: `C#`, `asp.net`, `sql`, `sql-server`, `sql-server-2008` - You have tagged everything here. Where do you want this result? In SQL or C#? How do you expect us to understand this, and why are you not filtering the records with the condition `FloorId = 2`?!

Comment: I want result in sql.I have filtered records with FloorId=2 but it shows Id as 3 and 4 and that I want to be 1 and 2.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: select * from tblname where FloorId=2

Comment: You can use Raging Bull's example. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`. It returns the sequential number of a row within a partition of a result set, starting at 1 for the first row in each partition.

Try this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) as ID,EmployeeId,EmpName,FloorId 
FROM tableName 
WHERE FloorId=2
```

The result will be like:

```
ID  EMPLOYEEID  EMPNAME FLOORID
1   def123      def     2
2   pqr123      pqr     2
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1946/1).

Read more about `ROW_NUMBER()` [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE  @TableName TABLE 
    ([ID] int, [EmployeeId] varchar(6), [EmpName] varchar(3), [FloorId] int)
;

INSERT INTO @TableName
    ([ID], [EmployeeId], [EmpName], [FloorId])
VALUES
    (1, 'abc123', 'abc', 1),
    (2, 'xyz123', 'xyz', 1),
    (3, 'def123', 'def', 2),
    (4, 'pqr123', 'pqr', 2)
;
;WITH CTE AS
(
select ID,EmployeeId,EmpName,ROW_NUMBER()OVER( ORDER BY ID ) RN,FloorId  from @TableName
)
select * from CTE 
WHERE FLOORid = 2
```